# HTML div and select spacing

Tags: html

I have the following HTML:

```
    <div class="blueBackground" style="height:350px; width:550px">

    <div class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="height:20px; margin:15px; clear:left;">
        <div style="width:150px"><%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Expense_return") %> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="height:20px; margin:15px; clear:left;">
        <div style="width:150px; float:left"><%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Wrong_Garment_Sounds") %> </div><select id="WrongGarmentSelector" class="fl" style="float:right; width:150px;"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="height:20px; margin:15px; clear:left;">
        <div style="width:150px; float:left"><%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Out_Of_Credit_Sounds") %> </div><select id="OutOFCreditSelector" class="fl" style="float:right; width:150px;"></select>
    </div>

    </div>
```

My aim is to create a blue box and then some rows. The second and third row in the above HTML are intended to have Text and a 'select' to the right of the text.

I have achieved this and they appear as intended. My problem is that I now want to decrease the width of the blue background, so it leaves a small gap to the left of the selector and then ends.

From what I can see:

- The width of the blue background is 550 px;
- The width of the text divs are 150 px.
- The width of the selectors are 150 px.
- There is a 15 px margin on the inner divs.
- The bluebackground div has no margin.
- The selector has no margin.

This would put the total width of the div and selector as:

> 150 + 150 + 30 = 330 px

However, if I make the bluebackground width 500px or less, it moves the selector to below the div.

This makes me think that I have not worked out the margins correctly. I have tried inspecting using the DOM explorer, but cant see the margins.

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't understand how backgrounds work. And what you're looking for is background-position, but I don't know if that would be enough. Can you post a fiddle with some code to work from?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly , you have 3 divs that have each one margins.

So the right calcul is : 150+30 +150 + 30+ 150+30 = 450+90 = 540 px ?

Tell me if you dont understand the calcul.

Edit: when you have margin:15px , you got margin-left:15px and margin-left:15px